# Display divs inline working in codepen but not in browser

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a multi-column dropdown menu, but i can't figure out why columns are not to the same height. The first one fits perfectly in parent div, the others not. I've also noticed that there isn't any display problem in codepen, with the same code, while in my browser doesn't work. You could see how it should be in codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxgQrL vs. how it actually is: https://ibb.co/fZLUkK.
Any help will be appreciated.

```css
.dropdown ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  background-color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 300px;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown a {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

.sale {
  background-color: #ee2b53;
  color: white;
  /*background-image: url(https://images3.nike.com/is/image/DotCom/PHN_PS/1U646_137_C_PREM/converse-chuck-taylor-monochrome-high-top-unisex-shoe.png?fmt=png-alpha);*/
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="col woman">
    <h4>Donna</h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Vedi Tutto</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sneakers &amp slip-on</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ballerine &amp flats</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mocassini &amp stringate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Décolleté</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stivaletti</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Abbigliamento &amp borse</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Capsule Limited edition</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col man">
    <h4>Uomo</h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Vedi Tutto</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sneakers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mocassini &amp slip-on</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stivali</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Giacche</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col child-f">
    <h4>Bimba</h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Vedi tutto</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Baby</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col child-m">
    <h4>Bimbo</h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Vedi tutto</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Baby</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col sale">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've noticed that the initial div height depends by the number of elements inside the div. But why does this happen and how can i solve this?

Comment: Most likely conclusion is that there is some css on your website that is changing your div. CodePen css is isolated to what you write. Check the debugger to see what additional css are acting on the element that shouldn't.

Comment: I've actually saved the entire project on CodePen (html + css) and it's still displaying the menu properly.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in IE and codepen doesn't work in IE so you're not able to replicate. Let me see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Haven't figured it out yet but maybe someone else can. The problem is with  grid-template-columns, it isn't supported in IE and you have to use -ms-grid-columns as well as -ms-display-inline for display property.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get grid-columns to work however, setting it

```
 display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
 display: inline-flex;
```

and removing

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
```

seem to do the job.